C++: Use free function as member function
I am currently trying to rewrite the Bullet Physics math library to allow for easier custom math implementations. Explicitly, I want to use glm.
Ideally I would like to just use:
using btVector3 = glm::vec3;

But btVector3 has many member functions that glm::vec3 does not have. Instead glm offers free functions. So instead of m.transpose() glm uses glm::transpose(m).
So I was wondering, if it is possible to interpret free functions as members. For example:
class A {};
int foo(const A&); // Or `int foo(const A*);`

A a;
int x = a.foo();   //=:= foo(a)

A* p = new A;
int y = p->foo();  //=:= foo(*p)

I know that member functions of A are compiled to functions taking an A* as the first argument (this). So I hoped I could just reinterpret the function as a member.
I tried using the pre-compiler to no avail.
#define foo() foo(this)    // This was an AI suggestion. But does not work.

I know I can write a wrapper class, but I do not like that I have to cast between the base and wrapper class. Implicit conversions are not working properly here as they do not work well with templates.
class A {};
int foo(const A&) { return 0; }

template<typename T>
int tmp(const T& t);

template<>
int tmp<A>(const A& a) { return 1; }

class Wrapper
{
private:
    A a;
public:
    operator A&() { return a; }
    operator const A&() const { return a; }

    int foo() { return ::foo(a); }
};

Wrapper a;
int x = a.foo();       //Works
int y = foo(a);        //Works
int z = tmp((A)a);     //Works, but I need to cast
int w = tmp(a);        //Compilation error (undefined reference to `int tmp(Wrapper const&)')

As a result common glm functions do not work well with a wrapper class. For example:
using A = glm::vec3;

glm::vec3 v(1.f);
float x = glm::dot(v,v);    // Works

Wrapper w(1.f);
float x = glm::dot(w,w);    // Does not work, as type can not be deduced properly


Free functions and members functions are very different things and are not interchangeable.

@RemyLebeau Yes, on the language level; but not on the object file level, which is what the OP tries to exploit. If you knew the name mangling scheme I suppose you could write a free function (perhaps using assembler for the symbol name to avoid the compiler's mangling) that happily links as a member function. (The caller would still need to see that member in the class declaration though.)

@Peter-ReinstateMonica That wouldn't work well with inline functions. Or with MS's __thiscall calling convention but I guess that's not a major concern for newly developed programs

How about the other way: use only free functions? you can have template <typename T> auto foo(T& t) -> decltype(t.foo()) { return t.foo(); }?

std::invoke(foo, a); std::invoke(&A::bar, a);

@Jarod42 Using only free functions is my preferred style for most functions, but requires many changes to the source code. Still I think I should write a script that turns all these calls to free calls. I just thought, that there might be a hack, that does so either implicitly or through some form of macro or compiler statement avoiding changes to the entire source code.
